# How to use one textbox value to call two ajax fuctions

Tags: html, ajax

I have an input field in html.

I want to invoke two ajax functions when text is entered into the field.
How to do it by passing events in html?

When I pass

```
onblur="function(this.value);another fun(this.value) "
```

only one ajax functions is called

Comment: You can call your second ajax on the success of first ajax. Like in your first ajax success function, call second ajax.

Comment: If we leave aside the obvious syntax errors in the code you've supplied that will prevent either function from being called: You are doing that already. If you have a problem with only one of them being called, then it isn't revealed in the code you've shared so far.

Comment: @ShreshttBhatt — Well, they *could*, but unless the contents of the request for the second one depend on the response for the first, that is probably just overcomplicating things.

Comment: Maybe the first function returns `false`?

Comment: @arkascha — Doesn't matter what the first function returns. It wouldn't stop further execution. The `onblur` function itself would have to return something to do that.

Comment: Assuming that the code supplied is an accurate representation of the real code with the sole exception of the function names being invalid (and that's a pretty big assumption), the only thing I can think of that could prevent the second function from being called is that the first function throws an exception. Which brings us back to my earlier point: The question needs [a proper test case](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Two alternatives come to mind:

1. you make a single "router" function handling the event which calls whatever functions you want to execute itself. Unlimited options, since it is up to you what you do inside that function.
2. you attach two handlers to the event. It seems you are using the in-code `onblur` attribute to fire your handler function. That is a very old fashioned style. Instead you can use the more modern style to attach arbitrary handlers to arbitrary events right after loading your page (or part of a page). That way you can attach different handlers to the same event without and downside.

Comment: The code in the question shows they are already doing option 1.

Comment: @Quentin Maybe I see something else in the OPs question. I cannot see a function calling two functions in there. I only see an in-code attribute with two function calls, the second in invalid syntax.

Comment: The value of an `onblur` attribute *is a function*. And both of the function calls from it are invalid syntax (which is obviously invalid because the OP has made up a terrible reduced test case that doesn't show the real problem and adds extra problems). As I mentioned in a comment on the question, that code can't have the effect described in the question (only one of the functions is called). It does however, show they have already got as far as you suggest going in your answer and that the problem lies elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered a similar issue.  the first function executes fine, but the second doesn't.  most browsers come with a javascript console - for viewing errors and such (usually CTRL-SHIFT-J brings it up).  Likely what's going on is your second function may have an error in it, whereas the first has no errors.  make sure you didn't miss a semi-colon, or more likely, you may have missed a closing parenthesis.  EG:

```
if (not banned_user("bob") {
  ...
}
```

i do this kind of typo ALL the time!  Drives me nuts.

So, bottom line, check the code of the second function.